# VS2010 C++ Remote Debugging on a service missing App in Modules list

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, service, remote-debugging

I'm trying to do remote debugging on a service using Visual Studio 2010.  The service is written in native C++ (no managed code).  Both local and remote machines are running Windows 7 Pro, 64 bit.

The service itself is a 32 bit app.

If I remotely attach to the process then I only see these modules in the modules list:
ntdll.dll, wow64.dll, wow64win.dll, wow64cpu.dll

If I run the service on my local machine and attach to it then all of the modules show up in the module list (45 of them).  The most notable missing module is, of course, the .exe itself.

If I remote debug to the same remote server using a different app, things work fine.

I've tried building the service as a release build with debug data and as a debug build, but get the same results for both.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by running **32 bit** variant of the VS2010 remote debug client, usually found in 
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x86\msvsmon.exe".

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the service to build as a 64 bit app and when I remote debug to it, everything works correctly.

So, at least based on this, looks like the remote debugging has 32/64 bit issues (?).

In my case, since everywhere we need to run this service is on a 64 bit machine, it's not a problem to run as 64 bit, so I'm done...

Comment: I'd still like to know if it's possible to solve this without rebuilding the target debugee as x64, so if anyone knows how, please share.

Comment: Unfortunately my grasp of this was never strong and I remember nothing about it from 5 years ago.   Since nobody else responded to the post, it suggests this is not a common issue.  I would expect a fundamental problem in 32/64 bit remote debugging to be a common issue, which suggests there may be better solutions out there than rebuilding as 64 bit.  In my case that fixed my problem and I moved on. I also don't use VS2010 anymore and it's always possible this was fixed in later releases of VS.  Wish I could help. Good luck!

Comment: I answered above :) Thanks.